# In sonarqube 5.6.6. I am unable to register secret key

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

I am following the instructions here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Settings+Encryption

I am in step 2.  I have created the secret file with a custom path.  I set the sonar.secretKeyPath property appropriately and rebooted the server.

When i navigate back to the config->general->security->encryption tab it still says "secret key is required to be able to encrypt properties"

I see no mention in the log (running at debug level) mentioning if it is even trying to use the secretkeypath or if it succeeded.

I can't seem to get past this point.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, are you sure the path you've used is valid ? Could you try to move the secret to default folder (~/.sonar/sonar-secret.txt) and remove the sonar.secretKeyPath setting ?

Answer (score 1):

My problem turned out to be because windows server does not seem to allow services to access the windows directory.  I was trying to "hide" the secret file here.  Even though the user had permissions, something else was blocking it.  Moving it to a non-system controlled directory fixed my problem